# Any Tutorials for Win32 SDK Programming?

Tags: c++, winapi, sdk

What are some good websites for Win32 SDK programming tutorials?

Answer (score 13):

The generally accepted bible for Win32 is the Petzold book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows%C2%AE-Fifth-Microsoft/dp/157231995X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X)

It's not online, but worth purchasing if you're serious about Win32, IMHO.

Comment: In my experience most of the MSDN docs assume you've read Petzold already, even for .NET framework. For example, a lot of the documentation on threads in .NET assumes you understand how they worked in Win32; without Petzold, I would have been utterly lost. If you look around, you can get used copies really cheap.  And he's a great writer.

Comment: Note that Mr. Petzold has released a 6th edition, but the 6th edition has removed the content related to Win32.  (Win32 hasn't changed, anyway) So, you'll need to get a hold of the 5th edition, NOT the 6th edition.

Answer (score 9):

The best online tutorial with regards to native Win32 programming would have to be [The Forger's Win32 API tutorial](http://winprog.org/tutorial/).

Answer (score 2):

This is my favorite: [Win32 Programming by Rector & Newcomer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201634929) It is massive and goes through all the basic concepts down to the nuts and bolts about Win32 programming.

BTW: Newcomer has a website also with examples (although more related to MFC) [here](http://www.flounder.com/mvp_tips.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely [Programming Windows, 5th edition](http://www.charlespetzold.com/books.html) by Charles Petzold.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a simple starter that will guide you through the basics. You can read "Windows Programming from the Ground Up" by Herbert Schildt. It will be a good forerunner to Charles Petzold. I read Herb Schildt first and then Charles Petzold, and I really was able to understand what Petzold was talking very easily.

Comment: While old, stuff like this: <http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/schildt.html> has made at least me very weary of Schildt. Just thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Petzold book (98), Richter book (4), Win32 group for undocumented apis and Windows source code (wine, etc), and Russinovich book also..

Answer (score 1):

Autohotkey source code: http://www.autohotkey.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

Avoid tutorials (by kids for kids)
Read the Petzold + Richter + Adv. Win32 Group (news://nntp.aioe.org/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32)

And avoid Newcomer (newbie in Win32, knows MFC only...)

Comment: Domi, you've got a serious attitude problem.  Are you going to answer everyone's questions like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the references and getting started tutorials for Win32 SDK programming at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663300.aspx).

Comment: A more direct link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399.aspx